# Finetuing pyvis to spread node spacing

Tags: graph, visualization, networkx, diagram, pyvis

I'm making a network map of my chess moves in the game played. Here's the code I wrote:

```
N = nx.Graph()
N.add_edges_from(main_list)

# Calculate node sizes based on their degrees
scale = 5  # Scaling the size of the nodes by 10*degree
d = dict(N.degree)
node_sizes = {node: scale * degree for node, degree in d.items()}

N2 = Network(notebook=True, height="1600px", width="100%", font_color="black", directed=True)

# Add nodes and edges to N2 with the calculated sizes
for node, size in node_sizes.items():
    N2.add_node(node, size=size)

for edge in N.edges():
    N2.add_edge(edge[0], edge[1])

# Define the options
options = {
  "edges": {
    "smooth": {
      "type": "continuous",
      "roundness": 0.15
    }
  },
  "physics": {
    "repulsion": {
      "centralGravity": 0.55,
      "springLength": 245,
      "nodeDistance": 795,
      "damping": 0.75
    },
    "maxVelocity": 14,
    "minVelocity": 0.75,
    "solver": "repulsion"
  }
}
# Convert the options dictionary to a JSON string and set it
options_str = json.dumps(options)
N2.set_options(options_str)

N2.show("better_map.html")
```

What changes should i make to increase the spread of the nodes? This is what my diagram looks like right now:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0p09.png)